# Trying to Modify Class Properties with PartialKeyPath in Swift

Tags: swift, immutability, keypaths

I am fairly new (a few months in) to swift so please excuse me if the question is trivial or duplicated.

I am trying to build a class which includes properties as well as an array of tuples (with 3 parameters) within which I store the keypath to the properties in the class as well as some other parameters which I would like to use to initialise/modify the class's properties

The code below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.  The real code is a lot more complex and uses about a hundred properties within the class.

```
class Strategy
 {
    var name = ""
    var value = 0.0
    var position = 0

    var param = [(path: PartialKeyPath<Strategy>, label: String, value: Any)]()

    init()
        {

        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.name, label: "Name",value: "Generic String"))
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.value, label: "Value",value: 375.8))
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.position, label: "Position",value: 34))

        for paramIndex in 0..<self.param.count  {

            let kp = self.param[paramIndex].path
            self[keyPath: kp] = self.param[paramIndex].value
        }
}

var myStrat = Strategy()

let kp = myStrat.param[0].path

print(myStrat[keyPath: kp])

myStrat[keyPath: kp] = " New String"
```

The reason for this approach is that I then have to display all the properties in an NSTableView so I can load the table via a loop on param rather than each property at the time.  Also, as the properties need to be editable via the NSTableView, I can use the row index, find the keypath to the property to modify and modify it.

I am getting a "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Any'" error on:

```
  self[keyPath: kp] = self.param[paramIndex].value
```

as well as on

```
  myStrat[keyPath: kp] = " New String"
```

which exemplifies how I would like to change the property name in the Strategy class

I think it has to do with self not being mutable but I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Thank you and apologies if this is a silly question of an inexperienced programmer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root,Value>` to modify properties of reference type objects (`class` instances). One sad thing is that you need to specify both type `Root` and `Value` statically.

For example:

```
if let keyPath = kp as? ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Strategy, String> {
    myStrat[keyPath: keyPath] = " A String"
}
```

So, to make your code work, you may need something like this:

```
protocol AnyKeyAccessible: class {
    subscript (anyKeyPath keyPath: PartialKeyPath<Strategy>) -> Any? {get set}
}
extension AnyKeyAccessible {
    subscript (anyKeyPath keyPath: PartialKeyPath<Strategy>) -> Any? {
        get {
            switch keyPath {
            case let keyPath as KeyPath<Self, String>:
                return self[keyPath: keyPath]
            case let keyPath as KeyPath<Self, Double>:
                return self[keyPath: keyPath]
            case let keyPath as KeyPath<Self, Int>:
                return self[keyPath: keyPath]
            // More cases may be needed...
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            switch keyPath {
            case let keyPath as ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, String>:
                self[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue as! String
            case let keyPath as ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, Double>:
                self[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue as! Double
            case let keyPath as ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, Int>:
                self[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue as! Int
            // More cases may be needed...
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can re-write your code using it:

```
class Strategy: AnyKeyAccessible, CustomStringConvertible {
    var name = ""
    var value = 0.0
    var position = 0

    var param = [(path: PartialKeyPath<Strategy>, label: String, value: Any)]()

    init() {
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.name, label: "Name",value: "Generic String"))
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.value, label: "Value",value: 375.8))
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.position, label: "Position",value: 34))

        for paramIndex in 0..<self.param.count  {
            let kp = self.param[paramIndex].path
            self[anyKeyPath: kp] = self.param[paramIndex].value
        }
    }

    //For debugging
    var description: String {
        return "name=\(name), value=\(value), position=\(position)"
    }
}

var myStrat = Strategy()

let kp = myStrat.param[0].path

print(myStrat[anyKeyPath: kp]) //-> Optional("Generic String")

myStrat[anyKeyPath: kp] = " New String"

print(myStrat) //-> name= New String, value=375.8, position=34
```

But, as I wrote in the comment of the code above, you may need many more `case`s to work with actual target classes. I'm not sure this really solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  Whilst playing with ReferenceWritableKeyPath I found a way that allows me not to specify the Value by putting it as Any.  I then declare my properties in the class as Any and it seems to work:

```
class Strategy
{
    var name = "" as Any
    var value = 0.0 as Any
    var position = 0 as Any

    var param = [(path: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Strategy, Any>, label: String, value: Any)]()

    init()
    {

        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.name, label: "Name",value: "Generic String"))
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.value, label: "Value",value: 375.8))
        self.param.append((path: \Strategy.position, label: "Position",value: 34))

        for paramIndex in 0..<self.param.count  {

            let kp = self.param[paramIndex].path
            self[keyPath: kp] = self.param[paramIndex].value
        }
    }

}

var myStrat = Strategy()

let kp = myStrat.param[0].path

print(myStrat[keyPath: kp])

myStrat[keyPath: kp] = "New String"

print(myStrat[keyPath: kp])
```

My only remaining doubt, being a novice to Swift if this may create problems in the future.  I have checked the types I get by using the keypaths and they match the properties types (String, Double and Int) even as I declared them as Any but initialised them as different types

Comment: With declaring your properties like `var name = "" as Any`, which is the same as `var name: Any = "" as Any`. So, you are declaring all the type of the properties as `Any`. For example, you can write `myStrat.name = 12.3`. So it disposes all benefits of statically typed language. If you can accept such things, I have no doubt `ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Strategy, Any>` would work for all properties of type `Any` in the future as far as Swift supports KeyPaths.

Comment: Thank you OOPer.  Very clear and helpful.  Coming from C (the Ansi variety) I am not completely used to the benefits of statically typed Swift, so I have checks in many places and the risk of a String sneaking into a Double will be minimal.  Thank you again for your answers.